# get the count of unread messages

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this requirement with our DB like shown below

I want to get the 3 columns `requestType`, `CategoryGroup`, and count of `readStatus` column

The result will show all the `requestType` along with `categoryGroup` and with if `readStatus` is false then it will show the count of it and if all `readStatus` is true in that same `requestType` then return 0.

also if `requestType` is `NULL` and Blank in same `categoryGroup` (from table A, subcategoryId 12 and 13 are from same `categoryGroup` in table B), then the categoryGroup should shown as BLANK and should hold the count of (`readStatus=0`) both NULL and BLANK

[image: Result count]

The query which I have written is returning only the columns and count in respect to `readStatus=false` and showing the total count of it.

```
select coalesce( m.requestType, "") as requestType,
  count(m.messageId) as count, 
  s.categoryGroup categoryGroup 
from mb_message m 
join mb_subcategory s on m.subCategoryId = s.subCategoryId 
where m.readStatus=0 
and m.storeId = ? 
and countryCode= ?
and m.modifiedDate >= ?
group by m.requestType, m.subCategoryId;
```

Expected result for above query is :

[image]

Comment: Can you add the expected result, in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
select
  requesttype, 
  sum(cnt) as cnt,
  categorygroup
from (
  select
    case when a.requesttype is null or a.requesttype = '' 
         then 'BLANK' else a.requesttype end as requesttype,
    case when a.readstatus = 0 then 1 else 0 end as cnt,
    b.categorygroup
  from tablea a
  join tableb b on b.subcategoryid = a.subcategoryid
) x
group by requesttype, categorygroup
```